# Passing parameter to jsp via tiles-defs

Tags: jsp, struts, el, tiles

I'm having a link in a JSP page as shown below

```
<li><a href="/test.do?version=10.1">download page</a></li>
```

In `struts-config.xml` we are forwarding it directly to `tiles-defs.xml` as shown below

```
<action path="/test" forward="testDef"/>
```

in `tiles-defs.xml`, we are having the entry as shown below

```
<definition name="testDef" extends="mainDef">
        <put name="__bodyContent" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ucspt/test.jsp"/>
    </definition>
```

`test.jsp` is the page which is body content of the page.

If you see the first link, I'm sending the version as 10.1. I want to access that version in `test.jsp`. How to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use JSP EL expression like

```
${param.version}
```

Comment: in JSP or tiles-defs.xml ?

Comment: Do you need it in JSP?